# Google Geocode not working in MVC project

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am trying to call a value (location) from a database. The value has been entered using Google Places Autocomplete. I succeed calling the value. However, what I would like to do is to use this value to show the location on a map when the page loads - but I somehow fail - any ideas?

UPDATED SNIPPET

```
<div id="errandPreviewLocationArea" class="manageArea row">
                <div id="errandPreviewLocationDisplay" class="errandomDisplay col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Location)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Location, new { @id = "errandPreviewLocationDisplayValue", @class = "manageDisplay" })
                </div>
                <div id="errandPreviewMapDisplay" class="errandomDisplay col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
                </div>
                <script>
                    function initMap() {
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('errandPreviewMapDisplay'), {
                            zoom: 11,
                            center: { lat: 47.3666700, lng: 8.5500000 }
                        });
                        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                        var address = document.getElementById('errandPreviewLocationDisplayValue').value;
                        window.alert(address); // I get the value here, everything beyond this point does not work
                        geocoder.geocode({ address : address }, function (results, status) {
                            if (status === 'OK') {
                                resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    map: resultsMap,
                                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                                });
                            } else {
                                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                            }
                        });
                    };
                </script>                
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="errandPreviewButtonSection" class="manageSection">
                <div id="errandPreviewButtonArea" class="manageArea row">
                    <button id="errandPreviewButton" class="manageButton col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10" type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </section>
    <div id="errandPreviewReturnToMenuSection" class="manageReturnToMenuSection">
        @Html.ActionLink("Return to Menu", "Index", "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "errandPreviewReturnToMenuButton", @class = "manageReturnToMenuButton" })
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCy75bDy97SpW9gb-9SFWS-xevm7oT0SoU&callback=initMap">
    </script>
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `status`?

Comment: None.. It does not even get there..

Comment: The map shows, but geolocatian fails

Comment: Does google have a throttle limit on the geolocation service? Are you reaching the limit?

Comment: Does the geolocation failure give you some error message?

Comment: How are you including the API?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman I think it is very unlikely that I am hiring a limit as I think it's around  10k calls. In top of that it never worked (not once). The failure does not give any message at all.

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the `results` object?

Comment: @geocodezip I am including the API as described on Google (of course entering the key): <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>

Comment: @IsaacKleinman the thing is I don't even get there... (neither results nor status...)

Comment: Could you show that in your question?  (preferably a [mcve] (SO code snippet) that demonstrates your issue

Comment: @geocodezip - snippet updated. I got to the status which returns 'OK'

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it to work by changing resultsMap to map:

```
<script>
                    function initMap() {
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('errandPreviewMapDisplay'), {
                            zoom: 11,
                            center: { lat: 47.3666700, lng: 8.5500000 }
                        });
                        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                        var address = document.getElementById('errandPreviewLocationDisplayValue').value;
                        window.alert(address); // I get the value here, everything beyond this point does not work
                        geocoder.geocode({ address : address }, function (results, status) {
                            window.alert(status);
                            if (status === 'OK') {
                                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    map: map,
                                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                                });
                            } else {
                                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                            }
                        });
                    };
                </script>
```